# Low ICC(1) and ICC(2) and model with varying intercept

Tags: multilevel-analysis

Please assume very basic understanding of statistics.

I've got 500 birth weights from 10 hospitals as a dependent variable and some explanatory variables. I thought that multilevel analysis would be a correct approach

I checked ICC(1) and ICC(2): ICC(1)=0.04 and ICC(2)=0.6 which are very low.

Then I built two models (using R) to check if my model would benefit from a random intercept:
gls(BirthWeight~1,data=xxx) and 
lme(BirthWeight~1,random=~1|Hospital,data=xxx). Then I compared these two models using anova(model1,model2) and p-value was 0.02. I understand the model improved when adding varying intercept.

My question is: **Can I use a model with varying intercept when ICC(1) and ICC(2) are so low?**